# Chrome cookie tab incredibly small and cannot be resized

Tags: google-chrome

One of my response cookies is getting blocked and I have no idea what's going on because Chrome is not rendering the table correctly:

[image]

Is there any way to force a resize?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the data to partially show by increasing the size of the font in the dev tools window.